# Stripe cancel subscription before end

Tags: node.js, nestjs, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe for payment subscription. In my app users can cancel subscription before end, but we wont to update user status from premium to free from this action. is there any webhooks event to listen to update my user status when his subscription actualy end?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen to specifically when a subscription ends you'd want the `customer.subscription.deleted` [event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.deleted).

However it sounds like you instead want to [downgrade your user](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade) to a free tier rather than cancel the subscription outright, in which case you'd want to listen to the `customer.subscription.updated` [event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.updated).